# Reading binary data and Distribute the data in grid file Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, binary

I am attempting to read flow data and distribute the data into the grid file for final plot. I have a MATLAB code for processing and it works successfully. I need this code to be transferred into Python but I am a beginner. It is always crashing when debugging, Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Data file(around 100mb in total):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3gtsmatq56pm0gc/AADUnNLjdrELjvdUy4wtDiiBa?dl=0

MATLAB code

```
%% Read Grid  grid file is used as a guide for the positon where data is put
fid = fopen('FLOW_phys_GRID_1.xyz', 'r');

a = fread(fid, 3, 'int');

Nx = a(1); % number of points in x direction
Ny = a(2); % number of points in y direction
Nz = a(3); % numebr of points in z direction

xx = fread(fid, Nx*Ny*Nz, 'float');
yy = fread(fid, Nx*Ny*Nz, 'float');

xx = reshape(xx, [Nx, Ny]);
yy = reshape(yy, [Nx, Ny]);

fclose(fid);

x = squeeze(xx(:,1));
y = squeeze(yy(1,:));

%% Read Data

fid = fopen('FLOW_phys.raw', 'r'); %flow data in binary format

a = fread(fid, 3, 'int');

Nx = a(1); % number of points in x direction
Ny = a(2); % number of points in y direction
Nz = a(3); % number of points in z direction

Ma = fread(fid, 1, 'float'); 
some_num = fread(fid, 1, 'float'); 
Re = fread(fid, 1, 'float');  
time = fread(fid, 1, 'float'); 

xx1 = fread(fid, 2*Nx*Ny*Nz, 'float'); 
xx1 = reshape(xx1, [Nx, 2*Ny, Nz]); 

fclose(fid);

[XX, YY] = meshgrid(x, y);

% plot (squeeze(xx1(2,:,1)));
h = pcolor(XX, YY, squeeze(xx1)');
set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
colorbar
```

Python code:

```
import struct
import numpy
import matplotlib

unpackformat_int = '<i'
unpackformat_flo = '<f'


fid = open('FLOW_phys_GRID_1.xyz', 'r+')

Nx = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]
Ny = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]
Nz = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]

aa = Nx*Ny*Nz

xx = struct.unpack('i'*aa, fid.read(aa*4))[0]
yy = struct.unpack('i'*aa, fid.read(aa*4))[0]

xx = xx.reshape([Nx, Ny])
yy = yy.reshape([Nx, Ny])

fid.close()

fid = open('FLOW_phys.raw', 'r+')

Nx = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]
Ny = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]
Nz = struct.unpack(unpackformat_int,fid.read(4))[0]

Ma = struct.unpack(unpackformat_flo, fid.read(4))[0]
some = struct.unpack(unpackformat_flo, fid.read(4))[0]
Re = struct.unpack(unpackformat_flo, fid.read(4))[0]
time = struct.unpack(unpackformat_flo, fid.read(4))[0]

bb = Nx*Ny*Nz

xx1 = struct.unpack('f'*bb, fid.read(bb*4))[0]
xx2 = struct.unpack('f'*bb, fid.read(bb*4))[0]

xx1 = xx1.reshape([Nx, Ny, Nz]) 
xx2 = xx2.reshape ([Nx, Ny, Nz])


fid.close()

[XX, YY] = numpy.meshgrid(xx, yy)

matplotlib.plot(XX,YY,xx2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. At the moment I don't think  it'st possible to answer this question because you have not provided an example for the structure of the files you are reading - can you provide an excerpt somehow? The semi-colons in Python code make me think you're struggling at those points (they are not needed, so i think they come from Matlab) and it also seems more verbose than it needs to be

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks so much in advance! MATLAB is a convenient tool for engineering stuffs. But I have to run the Python script for a specific project.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check out [mcve], downloading a 100 MB file is not ideal, unless it really can't avoided.

Comment: @roganjosh Is it difficult to write it the way I used with Python or did I do something wrong? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @roadrunner66 Thanks for the comment. Actually I don't suppose downloading is necessary. Cos the code was transferred from MATLAB, there seems some structural errors happened due to differences of commands between MATLAB and Python.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up with something coming up with work that I had to deal with so I didn't get chance to complete, I will try again this evening if you don't have an answer

Comment: @roganjosh Thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Without a specific error message it is hard to tell.  However, I see a series of likely problems.

First:

```
fid = open('FLOW_phys_GRID_1.xyz', 'r+')
```

This should be `'rb'`, which means "read binary". This is a binary file, not a text file.  `'r+'` mean "read and write", but you are not writing.  Also, you should always use `with open('FLOW_phys_GRID_1.xyz', 'r+') as fid:`, since this will automatically close the file safely when you are done with it.

Also, in MATLAB open files are represented by special numbers that identify the file to the MATLAB interpreter.  In Python, however, they are distinct objects, so to keep this in your mind better it might be good to use `fobj` instead of `fid` as the variable name.

Next:

```
xx = struct.unpack('i'*aa, fid.read(aa*4))[0]
yy = struct.unpack('i'*aa, fid.read(aa*4))[0]
```

In MATLAB, you read this in as a float, but in python you read it in as an integer.  More importantly, though, you are reading in `aa` numbers, but the `[0]` only keeps the first number.  In MATLAB you keep all of them.

Next:

```
xx = xx.reshape([Nx, Ny])
yy = yy.reshape([Nx, Ny])
```

`unpack` returns a tuple, which is inherently one-dimensional.  It has no `reshape` method, that is something numpy arrays have, but not python lists or tuples.  You would need to convert `xx` and `yy` to numpy arrays using something like `xx = np.array(xx).reshape([Nx, Ny])`, or better yet use numpy's `fromfile`, such as `xx = np.fromfile(fid, dtype='float', count=aa)`.  This reads the data in as a numpy array directly.

In fact I would suggest you use that everywhere.  The part where you get `Nx`, `Ny`, and `Nz` could be simplified to `Nx, Ny, Nz = np.fromfile(fid, dtype='i', count=3)`.  That syntax actually works with `unpack` also, but when working with a file the numpy approach is a bit simpler.

Also, the order of dimensions is different in numpy and MATLAB.  numpy (by default) uses the ordering derived from the array of the C programming language, while MATLAB exclusively uses the ordering of the Fortran programming language.  So to get the same array shape in Python as you have in MATLAB, you would need to reverse the first to axes, so `reshape([Ny, Nx])`, or later on `reshape([Ny, Nx, Nz])`.

Also, this will only work if `Nz` is always 1.  If it is any other number, this will fail even in MATLAB.

Next, from the MATLAB code:

```
x = squeeze(xx(:,1));
y = squeeze(yy(1,:));
```

You never do this in Python.  That also means the following part in Python is different than what you do in MATLAB:

```
 [XX, YY] = numpy.meshgrid(xx, yy)
```

Next:

```
bb = Nx*Ny*Nz

xx1 = struct.unpack('f'*bb, fid.read(bb*4))[0]
xx2 = struct.unpack('f'*bb, fid.read(bb*4))[0]
```

In MATLAB, you read `2*Nx*Ny*Nz`, but in Python you read `Nx*Ny*Nz` into two different arrays, which you never combine back into one.  This means you are plotting something different in Python than you are in MATLAB.  You also never `squeeze` or transpose the numpy array.

Finally:

matplotlib.plot(XX,YY,xx2)

First, you are doing `pcolor` in MATLAB but `plot` in Python.  These are completely different.  matplotlib has `pcolor` like MATLAB, so use that.

Second, there is no such thing as `matplotlib.plot`.  You need to do something like `from matplotlib import pyplot` then `pyplot.plot`.  Then you need to do `pyplot.show()` to actually show the plot.  However, it is usually a convention to do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` (and `import numpy as np`) to keep things shorter.

If you are doing this interactively, rather than in a script, you can do `plt.ion()` to make the plot show up immediately (or better yet use the IPython shell and use `%matplotlib`).  But in a script, you need to call `plt.show()` after all your formatting is done.

So here is how I would (roughly) implement what you are doing.  I don't have an example file to test, so it may not work exactly right, but hopefully it is enough to get you started:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


with open('FLOW_phys_GRID_1.xyz', 'rb') as fobj:
    Nx, Ny, Nz = np.fromfile(fobj, 'int32', 3)
    x = np.fromfile(fobj, 'float32', Nx*Ny*Nz).reshape(Ny, Nx, Nz)[:, 0, 0])
    y = np.fromfile(fobj, 'float32', Nx*Ny*Nz).reshape(Ny, Nx, Nz)[0, :, 0]

with open('FLOW_phys.raw', 'rb') as fobj:
    Nx, Ny, Nz = np.fromfile(fobj, 'int32', 3)
    xx1 = np.fromfile(fobj, 'float32', 2*Nx*Ny*Nz).reshape(2*Ny, Nx, Nz).squeeze().T

plt.pcolor(*np.meshgrid(x, y), xx1)
plt.show()
```